# Prevent disposal of PublishSubject (RxSwift)

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, rx-swift

I'm struggling with specific use-case incorporating RxSwift's PublishSubject.

For sake of simplicity unimportant details were omitted.

There is a MVVM setup. In VC I have a UIButton, on tap of which a network call should dispatch. In ViewModel I have a `buttonDidTapSubject: PublishSubject<Void>`.

```
class ViewModel {
  let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
  let buttonDidTapSubject = PublishSubject<Void>()
  let service: Service
  typealias Credentials = (String, String)
  var credentials: Observable<Credentials> {
   return Observable.just(("testEmail", "testPassword"))
  }
  init(_ service: Service) {
   self.service = service
   buttonDidTapSubject
    .withLatestFrom(credentials)
    .flatMap(service.login) // login method has signature func login(_ creds: Credentials) -> Observable<User>
    .subscribe(onNext: { user in print("Logged in \(user)") },
               onError: { error in print("Received error") })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
  }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
  let viewModel: ViewModel
  let button = UIButton()
  init(_ viewModel: ViewModel) { 
    self.viewModel = viewModel
  }
}
```

In controller's `viewDidLoad` I make a binding:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  button.rx.tap.asObservable()
    .subscribe(viewModel.buttonDidTapSubject)
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

**The problem is**, since network request can fail and Observable that is returned from `login(_:)` method will produce an error, the whole subscription to `buttonDidTapSubject` in ViewModel will be disposed. And all other taps on a button will not trigger sequence to login in ViewModel.

Is there any way to avoid this kind of behavior?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/Action
It is very helpful when binding to button and has nice features (like automatically handling enabled state)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `retry` to prevent finishing the subcription. If you only want to retry in specific cases or errors you can also use `retryWhen` operator

In the view model:

```
lazy var retrySubject: Observable<Void> = {
    return viewModel.buttonDidTapSubject
            .retryWhen { error in 
                if (error == .networkError){ //check here your error
                    return .just(Void())
                } else {
                    return .never() // Do not retry
                }
            }
}()
```

In the view controller I would have done it in another way:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  button.rx.tap.asObservable()
    .flatMap { [weak self] _ in
      return self?.viewModel.retrySubject
    }
    .subscribe(onNext: {
        //do whatever
    })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if still relevant - Use PublishRelay ( although it is RxCocoa )